# Data-annotations making property of a class mandatory as well as optional depending on controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

```
class RequiredOptionalId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have this property of class RequiredOptionalId that is a model. I access this from two controllers.

```
class RequiredIdController : ApiController
    {
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]RequiredOptionalId requiredOptionalId)
    {
                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        return BadRequest();
                    }
    }
    }

    class OptionalIdController : ApiController
    {
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]RequiredOptionalId requiredOptionalId)
    {
                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        return BadRequest();
                    }
    }
    }
```

I want to use data-annotations. But when i apply-

```
class RequiredOptionalId
    {
        [Required,Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

This create problem with post method of "OptionalIdController" as field is made required which is not true for this controller.

If I remove this anntoation i.e.

```
 class RequiredOptionalId
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }
```

This create problem with "RequiredIdController " as there is no validation for Id field.

I can add this in controller of "RequiredIdController " post method but i don't want to do that.

Is there any other way i can use these annotations or some filters to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can write an [ActionFilter](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) and pass the required parameters. 
Example using .Net Core.

Your action:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    [RequiredParameters("category","name")]
    public IActionResult Get(Request request)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
            return Json(request);

        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Your attribute:

```
public class RequiredParametersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string[] requiredProperties;

    public RequiredParametersAttribute(params string[] props)
    {
        requiredProperties = props;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        foreach (var property in requiredProperties)
        {
            //NOTE: assumption that action has only one parameter and looking only at first children in the object tree
            object obj = context.ActionArguments.FirstOrDefault().Value;
            if (obj?.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(obj) == null || obj.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(obj).Equals(GetDefaultValue(obj.GetType().GetProperty(property).PropertyType)))
                context.ModelState.TryAddModelError(property, property +" is required.");
        }
    }

    public static object GetDefaultValue(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetTypeInfo().IsPrimitive ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null;
    }
}
```

Your request class:

```
public class Request
{
    public int category { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Request: `/api/values?name=test` will return `{"category":["category is required."]}`.